# What is the proper way to seal / finish between drywall and concrete garage

Tags: drywall, finishing

Recently bought a house where in the garage there was a stripe of baseboard around the garage a few inches above the floor. I removed this because it was damage and cracked, and I am wondering what is the proper way to finish the gap. Since my garage is sunken a little there is a few inches of concrete on the wall, then the drywall.

I'm weary about just putting the baseboard back over it as there is a small gap between the studs and the concrete is not air tight.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use caulk to seal the gaps. But main thing to do is to use water-tolerant baseboard, such as vinyl 1x4 trim boards.

Concrete absorbs water and will leak it into any wood product

Comment: Or you could use a plastic baseboard. It comes in a roll with adhesive backing.